# how do I toast the number of checked boxes in my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

My code below works perfect when the activity loads with **all** checkboxes checked, or **all** checkboxes unchecked, and they are checked or unchecked from that point on, but the problem is that in reality the activity might load with SOME checkboxes checked.

I suppose the key is `count = 0;` If I could set `count` to the number of checked boxes when the form loads...

This is what I have in the `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`  of   my `adapter`, works for when **all** checkboxes start from a checked or unchecked position:

```
                //we want to keep track of checked boxes
                int count;
                count = 0;
                int size = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if (theContactsList.get(i).isSelected) {
                        count++;
                    }

                }

                  if (count == 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(context_type, "count is 0!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                        Toast.makeText(context_type, "The count is " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Comment: i have updated my answer..please check..

Comment: Can you please post your whole code with click listener. It will help to understand issue. Probably you are not decreasing the counter and that may causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help above, however I found another way which simplifies my code in the process. Useful as I am repeating this process across many activities.

In my activity I PUT the already checked boxes into `sharedpreferences` from the server with `Gson`:

```
       //Here, we PUT the arraylist into the sharedPreferences/*
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencescheckedContactsAsArrayList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
SharedPreferences.Editor editorcheckedContactsAsArrayList = sharedPreferencescheckedContactsAsArrayList.edit();
Gson gsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList = new Gson();
String jsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList = gsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList.toJson(checkedContactsAsArrayList);
                              editorcheckedContactsAsArrayList.putString("checkedContactsAsArrayList", jsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList);
editorcheckedContactsAsArrayList.commit();
```

In my `adapter` I GET those values from `sharedpreferences`, create an arrayList called `checkedContactsAsArrayList`:

```
//we are fetching the array list checkedContactsAsArrayList, created in the activity. with this we will put a tick in the checkboxes of the selected numbers
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencescheckedContactsAsArrayList = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context_type);
Gson gsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList = new Gson();
String jsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList = sharedPreferencescheckedContactsAsArrayList.getString("checkedContactsAsArrayList", "");
Type type2 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
 }.getType();
checkedContactsAsArrayList = gsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList.fromJson(jsoncheckedContactsAsArrayList, type2);
```

Then my `onBindViewHolder`

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

etc...

 holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    //on checkbox click
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                        Integer pos = (Integer) holder.check.getTag();

                        //if the checkbox is checked
                        if (holder.check.isChecked())

                        {
                            //we want to add the phone number of the checked row into our arraylist.

                            //add the checked number into the arraylist
                            checkedContactsAsArrayList.add(theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone());

                        } else {
                            //remove the checked number from the arraylist
                            checkedContactsAsArrayList.remove(theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone());

                        }
```

And also in my `onBindViewHolder`, no need for `loops` or anything:

```
                if (checkedContactsAsArrayList.size() == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(context_type, "count is 0!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(context_type, "The count is " + checkedContactsAsArrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. in your recyclerView adapter .. make **public static int count** variable.. **and in `onBindViewHolder()` add the `checkedChangeListener()` to your checkbox**

```
public static int count = 0; // field variable

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int 
                                                           position)
  {


        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
                                  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


            if (isChecked)
            {
                count ++;
                Toast.makeText(context_type, "count is " + count, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else 
            {


                count --;

      Toast.makeText(context_type, "count is " + count, 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
 }
```

> you could also check all checked or not.. like this ...

```
if(count == 0)
 {
    //nothing checked
  }
else if(count == mList.size())
   {
      //all checked
    }
```

> **In your adapter dont forget to add these to remember the checked positions:-**

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


       return position;

     }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {


        return position;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't work. keep getting 'count is 0!' regardless of what is checked or not. Also, app crashes on scrolling, mustn't be recycling checkboxes correctly.

Comment: add these two methods for the recyclerview to remember the checked positions .. *i assumed that you knew it ...so i dint mention* and also the crashing might be some other issue..but regardless add these two methods and test...

Comment: Yes, getItemId was missing, shall try in a while, thanks.

Comment: and also *make the check change listener in `onBindViewHolder()`

Answer (score 1):

Get all views and count checked checkboxes with:

```
int checked = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rv.getChildCount(); i++) {

    try {
        CheckBox checkBox = rv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) checked++;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Toast.makeText(this, "Checked: " + checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

where `rv` is your recyclerview and `R.id.checkbox` is your checkbox id

It works for me but make sure adapter has created views for recyclerview.